# Can span.classname css be applied on div.className

Tags: css

Is there any way to use this css definition for div element

```
span.classsName{
 width:100px;
}
```

for example

```
<div class="classsName"></div>
```

will not work, but you see what I am trying to achieve.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 3):

Call it `.className{  }` without the span, and you can use it on any field.

Comment: So without .className{ } it cannot be used on div?

Comment: If you add `span` in front of it, then you can use it with span only. If you call it .className, that means you are defining a CSS Class, and can be used by any field on the page with the attribute `class="className"`

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of that, but I am looking for way or hack to use it with span, because right now I have that problem. Thanks.

Comment: maybe you should clarify more, what exactly is the problem, is it that you can't change the CSS? Because in it's current state it's not correct to use with a div, even if you found a hack. Explain more what exactly what you want and we might be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the `span` to just leave `.classsName`, which will then be applied to any element with that class name, regardless of tag name.

Alternatively, you could change the selector to `span.classsName, div.classsName` to apply to both `span` and `div` elements with that class.

Answer (score 0):

How about
`.classsName{
 width:100px;
}`

or
`span.classsName, div.className {
 width:100px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You could do (just remove the `span`):

```
.classsName{
    width:100px;
}
```

The `.xxxx` CSS naming applies to HTML elements whose `class` matches CSS `xxxx` name. Alternatively:

```
span.className, div.className {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Which means that the `div` and `span` with the class `className` will have the same width.

Comment: I am aware of that, but I have priority to use change css as less as possible and not to change html structure at all. Thanks.

Comment: @SonOfOmer, well, that's what my solution does. It won't change the structure of your HTML in any way.

Comment: neither I should change the css

Comment: Then you are not very clear. What are you trying to do and what are your restrictions?